# Trigger on click event automatically when visiting a specific url

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question might be weird but I really need to trigger an onclick() event when visiting a web page.

Here's my code:
https://github.com/Kakise/Blog/blob/master/themes/cactus/layout/_partial/scripts.ejs#L66

```
var disqus_shortname = '<%= theme.disqus.shortname %>';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#disqus-load').on('click', function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "//" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
        dataType: "script",
        cache: true
    });
    $(this).fadeOut();
}); });
```

I'd like that when I visit this url with #disqus_thread in the end, it acts as if I clicked on the #disqus-load div and loads the comments.

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you generalize the code in the click handler into a common function and call it in document.ready and in other areas where it needs to be bound to events and pass `disqus_shortname` as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to do something upon loading you could always do `.onload` a better on would be JQuery's `trigger` method :

```
$('some_obj').trigger('click')
```

---

What this will do is that immediately upon load it will automatically `trigger` the click function (requires JQuery)

---

## Resources :

- [`.trigger` W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_trigger.asp)
- [`.trigger` Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

---

Answer (score 1):

if clicking `div#disqus-load` does it then you can trigger a click response through jQuery -

```
$("#disqus-load").trigger('click');
```